# Is $e^{i+\pi}$ irrational or not?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi

Since we know that the value of $e$, $i$, and $\pi$ are irrational reals, how about $$e^{i+\pi}\;?$$ Is it still irrational (that is, not a Gaussian rational)?
The problem make me curious until now.

Comment: Obviously, since it is not even real.

Comment: Please tell us what you think $e^{i+\pi}$ is

Comment: I didn't know what exactly e^(i+pi) is. But, I think some of them can be find in complex number.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the definition of "rational/irrational" can be extended to the whole complex field and *not only* be restricted to the real axis...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_rational_points_on_the_unit_circle irrationality does not depend on not being real.

Comment: Well, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number , here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrational+number and here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalNumber.html , just to mention a few, says otherwise, @Arjang . In all this "irrational" number is considered a real number. I'd also go with this definition, btw.

Comment: I misread @Arjang 's comment: too many negatives too close to each other for me. Ithought he said "irrational does not depend on *being* real" ...

Comment: The definition of rational being automatically inferred is the narrow one, maybe calling it real irrational number as oppose to rational number, one can very well go with Guessian Rationals when working in complex domain http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational

Comment: No matter whether you consider the concepts of rational/irrational as restricted to the real numbers or not, in no case is $\mathrm i$ an irrational number. Either it is rational, or it is neither rational nor irrational.

Comment: $i$ is _not_ irrational. It's not even real.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Building off of Clive's answer, if $e^\pi \cos 1$ and $e^\pi \sin 1$ were both rational numbers, then so would be their quotient $\tan 1$.  But $\tan 1$ is irrational as a consequence of the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem, because that theorem implies that $e^{2i}$ is transcendental, and because $e^{2i}=\dfrac{i-\tan 1}{\tan 1+i}$.  Therefore $e^{\pi+i}$ cannot have both its real and imaginary parts rational.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean *rational* in the usual sense $-$ as a subset of the reals $-$ then $e^{i+\pi}$ is certainly not rational since it is not real. But the question of whether it's a *[Gaussian rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational)* $-$ that is, its real and complex parts are rational $-$ may not be easy to prove. Notice that
$$e^{i+\pi} = e^{\pi}\cos 1 + i e^{\pi}\sin 1$$

Given irrational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ it's often quite hard to determine whether $\alpha^{\beta}$ and $\alpha \beta$ (and $\alpha + \beta$) are rational or irrational. For example, it is not currently known whether $e\pi$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: It would suffice to show that $\tan 1$ is irrational.  I guess that is true but don't know how to prove it and don't have a reference.  (Incidentally, it is known that $e^\pi$ is irrational.)

Answer (score 2):

$e^i=\cos1+i\sin1$. (By Euler's Formula)

So $e^{i+\pi}=e^\pi\cos1+ie^\pi\sin1$, which is non-real and, of course, irrational.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_rational_points_on_the_unit_circle irrationality does not depend on not being real.

Comment: @Arjang: Apparently you are using a different definition of rational than ᴊ ᴀ s ᴏ ɴ.  That does not mean that JASON's interpretation is incorrect.  It is common for rational to refer only to elements of the set of rational numbers, $\mathbb Q$, whereas you seem to prefer that it means an element of $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Arjang: I disagree. That wikipedia article talks about rational points on a curve, that is points such that all their coordinates are rational. The set of rational numbers is most certainly a subset of the reals.

Comment: @Arjang: There is a subtle issue of terminology here. A rational *number* is necessarily real. A rational *point* in the complex plane is one with rational coefficients.

Comment: I agree with @JohnBentin, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: The definition of rational being automatically inferred is the narrow one, maybe calling it real irrational number as oppose to rational number, one can very well go with Guessian Rationals when working in complex domain http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational

Comment: @Arjang: If you go that way, then you should IMHO give a compelling reason as to why you decide to call elements of the particular field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$ "complex rationals" rather than elements of all $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$? After all, these are all numbers of a quadratic extension field of the rationals. Thus they can all be thought of having rational coordinates w.r.t. the basis $\{1,\sqrt{-d}\}$. Abracadabra! You have redefined rationality to the point of including $\sqrt{2}$ among them (pick $d=-2$). This is just plain absurd.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes, Indeed it is absurd, but the problem was with  using the concept of irrationality where it has no meaning! as Soham Chowdhury said : $i$ is not irrational. It's not even real. The very definition of irrational depending on not being rational means even a potato should be considered irrational because it is not rational, it only makes sense in the domain of reals.

Comment: Sorry about being a bit blunt in my previous comment. But a Gaussian rational is simply not necessarily rational. In the same sense elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ would be called Eisensteinian rationals. The algebraic integers of these two fields are widely known as  Gaussian (resp. Eisensteinian) integers. All basic theory of algebraic number fields. But we never call all elements of algebraic number fields "rationals".

Comment: @Arjang: Agree with your point of rationality being meaningless outside the domain of reals.